# Are these two proofs equivalent and correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n=\frac{\cos(\pi n)}{2^n}$. I proved the convergence of this sequence in two different ways, and I wonder if both are equally right.

A) I noticed $b_n=\cos(\pi n) = \{1, -1, 1, -1,...\}$ so $|b_n|=1$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n} =0$ and therefore the sequence converges to $0$.

B) I noticed that $a_{2n}= \frac{\cos(2n\pi)}{2^{2n}}=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$, because $\cos(2n\pi)$ is always $1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and the limit tends to $0$. Then I did the same noticing that $a_{2n-1}$ tends to $0$ with the numerator always being $-1$. Because $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$ make up for all values of $a_n$, then the sequence $a_n$ tends to $0$ for all $n$.

Are both procedures formally correct? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: *A third alternative coming from the comments*

C) We can see that  $\forall \epsilon > 0$ it is the case that $|a_n-0|< \epsilon \iff \frac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon \iff -\log_2(\epsilon) < n$, which by the definition of limits means $a_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Both are right, but I wouldn't call them equivalent. The first assumes that if $|a_n|\to 0,$ then $a_n\to 0.$ The second one relies on the theorem that if you can split a sequence into two subsequences, and both subsequences converge to the same value, then the whole sequence converges to that value.

Comment: They are fine. The first is using that $\lim_n|x_n|=0\implies\lim_nx_n=0$, while the second is using that $\lim_{n\\n\in A}x_n=L\wedge \lim_{n\\n\in B}x_n=L\implies \lim_{n\\n\in A\cap B}x_n=L$.

Comment: The direct $\epsilon-N$ proof is that if $N=\lceil-\log_2 \epsilon\rceil$ and $n>N$ then $\left|a_n-0\right|=|a_n|=\frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon.$

Comment: I'd say the are both valid but making assumptions that may need to be justified A) assumes that if $|a_n| \to 0$ then $a_n \to 0$.  Can you justify that? (it is true) B) assumes that if $a_{2n}\to k$ and $a_{2n-1} \to k$ then $a_n\to k$.  Can you justify that?  (You may need to specify that $\{a_k\} = \{a_{2n}\}\cup \{a_{2n-1}\}$.) ... by the way a "straightforward" for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $N > \log_2 \frac 1{\epsilon}$ then $n> N\implies |a_n - 0| < \epsilon$ is nearly as easy.

Comment: What Thomas Andrews said.

Comment: In the $\epsilon-N$ proof, you can also just choose $N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right\rceil.$ Then if $n\geq N,$ $2^n>2^{N}>N\geq\frac1{\epsilon}$ so $|a_n-0|=\frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon.$

Comment: On second thought.  If I assume $\frac 1{2^n}\to 0$ is a given, then trying to prove $\pm \frac 1{2^n}\to 0$ via an $\epsilon, N$ proof would be reinventing the wheel.  Easier to simply prove that $a_n\to 0\iff |a_n|\to 0$ via $|a_n - 0| = ||a_n| - 0|$ so the definition of $a_n \to 0$ would imply and be implied by $|a_n| \to 0$.

Comment: You would give up B) if you considered the sequence $a_n=2^{-n}\cos (n\alpha)$ for a fixed $\alpha$ or more generally $a_n=2^{-n}b_n$ where $b_n$ is a bounded sequence.

Comment: I have added the proof suggested by @ThomasAndrews for the sake of completion. I thank you all for your comments. Thomas, if you want you can pass the content of your comments to a full answer, I will mark it as correct.